# How to solve shift/reduce conflict using operator precedence?

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, dfa, lr-grammar

So I have this grammar I'm trying to build an LR(1) table for

```
      E' -> E
      E -> E + E
      E -> E * E
      E -> ( E )
      E -> a
```

So far, this my table

[image]

I'm trying to solve the conflicts here. I thought about changing the grammar to postfix instead of infix but I'm not really sure if I can do that. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're trying to resolve the conflicts using precedence, you should use the precedence resolution algorithm. It's described in the Dragon Book (see Parsing Ambiguous Grammars), in the [Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Precedence), and in any number of SO answers, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26785562/1566221). If after reading the material, you have a specific question about this simple algorithm, feel free to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your grammar, with precedence:

```
E' -> E
E -> E + T
E -> T
T -> T * F
T -> F
F -> ( E )
F -> a
```

Don't forget the extra `E  -> T`, and `T -> F`, as without it the grammar will be useless.

**Note:** This will not work with LR(0), because you'll get a conflict.

Comment: Can you explain this more? I don't really understand how you decided to replace E-> E+E with E->E+T?

Comment: @RubaSbeih -- It changes how the nodes are created; `a` will be a leaf one, etc.